# Rope climbing gymnastic tricks -- what are they called?

Tags: gymnastics

I'd like to learn some cool tricks that I could use on the kind of rope that's found hanging from the ceiling in schools' gymnastic halls. I've tried to search, but all I can find is tips on how to climb them. I don't have any trouble climbing ropes, but want to know what else could be done while hanging in them.

What's the right term to search for? I couldn't find it in Overcoming Gravity.

Comment: are you talking about "arial silks", by any chance?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerial_silk
They're climbing a curtain (or pair of curtains), and performing acrobatic manuevers.

Comment: That kind of skills, except they're performed on a rope.

Comment: In the meanwhile, try training to climb upside-down... looks pretty darn impressive. :)

Answer (score 2):

"Spanish Web" or "Corde Lisse"

There is a nice overview at this [Aerial Arts FAQ](http://community.simplycircus.com/tutorials/aerial/aerial_arts_faq.htm).